# The type or namespace name 'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

Using Visual Studio 2013. I have added namespace System.Web.Http.Routing, but still, it says it couldn't be found. I have been following this tutorial, don't know if it helps: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#route-constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Namespace System.Web.Mvc.Routing
```

will do the trick.